# ASP.Net Entity Group and Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have this code, and works perfect.

```
var statisticsLeadChar = from order in db.StatisticLeads
    where 
    order.Date.Month == DateTime.Today.Month
    && order.Date.Year == DateTime.Today.Year
    orderby order.Date descending
    group order by order.Date.Day into users
    select new StatisticLead()
    {
        StatisticLeadId = users.Count(),
    };
```

but.. I want to add "Date", like this (below) but not work. I want to get not only StatisticLeadsId but also it = date

```
StatisticLeadId = users.Count(),
Date = order.Date
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your group by is according to the day part of the date, any order in your group may have a different date, which date do you want to select? the max? min? maybe the average?

Comment: Only Day, Day is one. Not Datetime. Just day ( :